# What is the noun for "no sort order"?

Tags: sorting, terminology

Normally, one would say that something is sorted chronologically (oldest to newest) or alphanumerically (first to last), however what is it called when the sort order does not matter, in which no effort has been taken on behalf of the program to arrange the items in an array.

Comment: How about "unsorted"?

Comment: Are you sure a noun is what you want, and not an adjective? "Sorted chronologically" isn't a noun.

Comment: _natural order_ (= order as encountered, without any extra effort)? Though _unsorted order_ would be more explicit. This is a CS term.

Comment: "Ordered arbitrarily"?

Comment: "Natural order" can mean (and I would say, normally means) ordered according to how the elements overload the comparison operators, or (e.g. in Java) according to how they implement the `Comparable` interface; this is as opposed to sorting with a different comparator or key function. From [the docs for that interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), *"This ordering is referred to as the class's natural ordering, and the class's compareTo method is referred to as its natural comparison method."*